# Where can I find open data about sport's competitions?

Tags: data-request, sports

I have been looking for formula one racing open data, but I haven't found anything...

I'd need open data about any sports or about topics like health, university etc... to build up a project of datawarehouse

Answer (score 4):

Formula One racing open data (outdated) here: https://github.com/opensport/formula1.db

In general, Gerald Bauer has been compiling and releasing lots of sports open data.  You can read about some of it here: http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2014/05/06/open-data-world-cup.html

Cheers,

Dan